# Email Button Is not showing

Tags: email

I created a new custom object in sandbox environment, and i want to send a  mail by using send an button in activities related list but it is not showing, log a call button is visiable to me, but send an email button is not visiable what i want to do any suggestions

[image: Activity Image]

when i do it showing like this but in quote record email button is not visiable

[image: activity image2]

Comment: edit page layout of custom object, in Activity History related list there is tool icon, click on that, you will get column selection section and button section, click on button section, there you see the "send an email" button, just check on that.. it may solve your problem

Comment: @Bharat as per u r suggestion i do it but it is not showing in record, in pagelayout it is showing can you check my second image

Comment: please look for my ans, this is hapening due to email setup

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is sanbox, change deliverability setting under "Email Administration" as follows:

Go to Setup | Email Administration | Deliverability.

Change Access level picklist to "All email".

Click save button.

You should now see 'send an email' button in activity history related list

Comment: This does not hide / show the email button, but merely prevents sandboxes from sending outbound emails uninentionally.

Answer (score 3):

Check that your permissions are set up correctly.  In particular, there is a "Send Email" setting on the profile that needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

*'Send an Email'* button is available in layout configuration but does not appear on layout.

- Email Deliverability - correct
- All Profile permissions - correct

Found the following knowledge article:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232945&language=en_US&type=1

> The "Send Email" button will be visible only on the detail view of the
>   object record in Lightning Experience but not in Salesforce Classic
>   UI.

Do they disable sending of emails for Salesforce Aloha (Classic)?

Answer (score 0):

This button / action visibility within a Lightning Community is controlled via the Global Publisher layout. If the Email action is not present on the layout then it will not display on the Activity History related list. You can confirm this by going doing the following:

1. Go to Setup > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts > Global Layout.
2. Edit the Global Layout.
3. Locate the Email Mobile & Lightning Action called "Email".
4. Add this to the Layout.
5. Save

Clear your browser cache and log back into the Community and access a record where the Send Email action was not present, it should now be restored.